# Kubeadm with containerd cannot use locally loaded images

Tags: kubernetes, rhel8, kubeadm, containerd

I'm trying to build kubernetes with containerd in bare-metal server (RHEL8).

There's no Internet connection so I manually downloaded needed images (e.g. k8s.gcr.io/kube-scheduler:v1.22.1) and loaded them using "ctr image import".

The images seem to be loaded successfully.

```
#ctr images ls -q
k8s.gcr.io/coredns/coredns:v1.8.4
k8s.gcr.io/etcd:3.5.0-0
k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver:v1.22.1
k8s.gcr.io/kube-controller-manager:v1.22.1
k8s.gcr.io/kube-proxy:v1.22.1
k8s.gcr.io/kube-scheduler:v1.22.1
k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.5
```

Then I executed "kubeadm init" but it failed with ImagePull errors.

```
#kubeadm init --kubernetes-version=1.22.1 --cri-socket=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.22.1
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
        [WARNING FileExisting-tc]: tc not found in system path
[preflight] Pulling images required for setting up a Kubernetes cluster
[preflight] This might take a minute or two, depending on the speed of your internet connection
[preflight] You can also perform this action in beforehand using 'kubeadm config images pull'
error execution phase preflight: [preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:
```

How can I let kubeadm to use local images? Or is it OK to ignore these preflight errors?

Edit:
This procedure (manually loading images instead of executing kubeadm config images pull) worked well when with docker and CentOS7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that I had to load images to the `k8s.io` namespace of the containerd so that Kubernetes can recognize them. I was importing the images to the wrong namespace (default).

```
ctr -n k8s.io images import xxx.tar
...
```

After loading all the images that Kubernetes needs, kubeadm init worked well without executing
`kubeadm config images pull`. The images that Kubernetes can use are shown in
`ctr -n k8s.io images ls` or `crictl images`.

```
# crictl images
IMAGE                                                          TAG                 IMAGE ID            SIZE
k8s.gcr.io/coredns/coredns                                     v1.8.4              8d147537fb7d1       47.7MB
k8s.gcr.io/etcd                                                3.5.0-0             0048118155842       296MB
k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver                                      v1.22.1             f30469a2491a5       130MB
k8s.gcr.io/kube-controller-manager                             v1.22.1             6e002eb89a881       123MB
k8s.gcr.io/kube-proxy                                          v1.22.1             36c4ebbc9d979       105MB
k8s.gcr.io/kube-scheduler                                      v1.22.1             aca5ededae9c8       53.9MB
k8s.gcr.io/pause                                               3.5                 ed210e3e4a5ba       686kB
```

Answer (score 1):

To manually pull the images execute the following:

```
kubeadm config images list
kubeadm config images pull
```

There is also a section for [running kubeadm without an internet connection](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-init/#running-kubeadm-without-an-internet-connection) in the Kubernetes docs.

Comment: Actually I wanted to do that but there’s no Internet connection. With docker and CentOS7, I successfully installed kubernetes using the same procedure.